# Chrome Extension - will adding "identity" permission will cause warning on autoupdate?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to know if adding "identity" permission during the next update will disable the extension (cause a warning) for current users. Documentation is silent - neither [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) nor "[Permission Warnings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings)" pages contain any info about it.

Comment: You can test it yourself as described in your second link. AFAIK there's no warning.

Comment: Yeah, you're right - it's easier to test it out. Though uploading dummy app and then update with permissions seems easier than setting up autoupdate server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did ask the user to accept new permissions.

The solution is to make those permissions optional, and ask for them when needed.

**Manifest file**

```
"optional_permissions": [ "identity", "identity.email" ],
```

**JS**

```
/* askPermissions: Ask user for permissions. Returns promise. 
    Example: askPermissions().then( () => { /* do stuff */ } ));
*/
askPermissions() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let permissions = [ "identity", "identity.email" ];
        let onAnswer = ( isGranted ) => {
            return isGranted ? resolve() : reject();
        };
        chrome.permissions.request( { permissions }, onAnswer );
    });
},
```